# how to get relative date from absolute date ? in shell

Tags: shell, date, unix, format, relative-date

Consider dates of the format:

- `2022-06-18T11:03:40+0800`
- `1655107420`
  ...

How could you get dates with relative information (i.e the time delta `N minutes ago`):

```
Saturday, June 18, 2022 at 11:32:30 (3 minutes ago)
Saturday, June 18, 2022 at 11:19:03 (17 minutes ago)
```

Comment: @OleV.V. yes it is